# CsvHelper: How to access already mapped class properties within Inline Type Conversion (ConvertUsing)

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I was wondering if it is possible to access a property from the mapped class during the mapping process with the `CsvReader`. Please see the example below.

```
public class FooCsvMap : ClassMap<FooModel>
{
    public FooCsvMap(BarService barService)
    {
        Map(m => m.BarObject).ConvertUsing(row => barService.Lookup(row.GetField(0)));
        Map(m => m.Bar2).ConvertUsing(row =>
        {
            // ?? Is it possible to access m.BarObject? If yes how?
            var barObject = row.model.BarObject;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using `CsvWriter` you could access `BarObject` directly.

```cs
var barObject = row.BarObject;
```

Unfortunately, if you are using `CsvReader`, I believe you can only access the raw row data because the `FooModel` object has yet to be created at this point. So you would have to do something like this.

```cs
var barObject = barService.Lookup(row.GetField(0));
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidSpecht! Yes I'm using the `CsvReader` (I will add that in my questions). Currently, I do the lookup twice. If the `FooModel` object isn't created at this point that answers my question. Thanks again!